# Using XSLT to transform default XML of view

Tags: list, xml

I have a public website on which I need to display a simplified version of a list view I have set up in SharePoint.

I am successfully using the techniques described on [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2009/05/01/getting-xml-data-from-a-sharepoint-list-the-easy-way.aspx) to get the XML of the view, but it is overly complicated and I can't get my jQuery AJAX code to handle the namespaces properly.

I have written the following XSLT but am encountering issues. Forgive in advance as as I am a XSLT newbie.

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <activeRFPs>
    <xsl:for-each select="z:row">
        <rfp>
            <title>
                <xsl:value-of select="@ows_RFP_x0020_Link" />
            </title>
            <applicationStart>
                <xsl:value-of select="@ows_Application_x0020_Period_x0020_S" />
            </applicationStart>
            <applicationEnd>
                <xsl:value-of select="@ows_Application_x0020_Period_x0020_E" />
            </applicationEnd>
            <programStart>
                <xsl:value-of select="@ows_Program_x0020_Start_x0020_Date" />
            </programStart>
            <publicURL>
                <xsl:value-of select="@ows_Public_x0020_Guidelines_x0020_Do" />
            </publicURL>
        </rfp>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </activeRFPs>
</xsl:template>
```

The source XML from SharePoint looks like this:

```
<xml xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
 xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
 xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
 xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here is the source XML:

```
<xml xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
 xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
 xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
 xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
<s:Schema id='RowsetSchema'>
<s:ElementType name='row' content='eltOnly' rs:CommandTimeout='30'>
  <s:AttributeType name='ows_RFP_x0020_Link' rs:name='RFP Link' rs:number='1'>
     <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='512' />
  </s:AttributeType>
  <s:AttributeType name='ows_Application_x0020_Period_x0020_S' rs:name='Application Period Start Date' rs:number='2'>
     <s:datatype dt:type='datetime' dt:maxLength='8' />
  </s:AttributeType>
  <s:AttributeType name='ows_Application_x0020_Period_x0020_E' rs:name='Application Period End Date' rs:number='3'>
     <s:datatype dt:type='datetime' dt:maxLength='8' />
  </s:AttributeType>
  <s:AttributeType name='ows_Program_x0020_Start_x0020_Date' rs:name='Program Start Date' rs:number='4'>
     <s:datatype dt:type='datetime' dt:maxLength='8' />
  </s:AttributeType>
  <s:AttributeType name='ows_Public_x0020_Guidelines_x0020_Do' rs:name='Public Guidelines Doc URL' rs:number='5'>
     <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='512' />
  </s:AttributeType>
</s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
<rs:data>
<z:row ows_RFP_x0020_Link='http://www.google.com, Google Search Engine' ows_Application_x0020_Period_x0020_S='2012-06-22 00:00:00' ows_Application_x0020_Period_x0020_E='2012-07-20 00:00:00' ows_Program_x0020_Start_x0020_Date='2012-10-01 00:00:00' ows_Public_x0020_Guidelines_x0020_Do='http://www.yahoo.com' />
</rs:data>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
<xsl:for-each select="z:row">
```

to

```
<xsl:for-each select="/xml/rs:data/z:row">
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, so I just tested it and this worked for me:

Source XML:

```
<xml xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882' 
 xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882' 
 xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset' 
 xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'> 
<s:Schema id='RowsetSchema'> 
<s:ElementType name='row' content='eltOnly' rs:CommandTimeout='30'> 
  <s:AttributeType name='ows_RFP_x0020_Link' rs:name='RFP Link' rs:number='1'> 
     <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='512' /> 
  </s:AttributeType> 
  <s:AttributeType name='ows_Application_x0020_Period_x0020_S' rs:name='Application Period Start Date' rs:number='2'> 
     <s:datatype dt:type='datetime' dt:maxLength='8' /> 
  </s:AttributeType> 
  <s:AttributeType name='ows_Application_x0020_Period_x0020_E' rs:name='Application Period End Date' rs:number='3'> 
     <s:datatype dt:type='datetime' dt:maxLength='8' /> 
  </s:AttributeType> 
  <s:AttributeType name='ows_Program_x0020_Start_x0020_Date' rs:name='Program Start Date' rs:number='4'> 
     <s:datatype dt:type='datetime' dt:maxLength='8' /> 
  </s:AttributeType> 
  <s:AttributeType name='ows_Public_x0020_Guidelines_x0020_Do' rs:name='Public Guidelines Doc URL' rs:number='5'> 
     <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='512' /> 
  </s:AttributeType> 
    </s:ElementType>
  </s:Schema>
  <rs:data>
    <z:row ows_RFP_x0020_Link='http://www.google.com, Google Search Engine' ows_Application_x0020_Period_x0020_S='2012-06-22 00:00:00' ows_Application_x0020_Period_x0020_E='2012-07-20 00:00:00' ows_Program_x0020_Start_x0020_Date='2012-10-01 00:00:00' ows_Public_x0020_Guidelines_x0020_Do='http://www.yahoo.com' /> 
  </rs:data>
</xml>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="rs z o s dt msxsl" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office" xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <activeRFPs>
      <xsl:for-each select="/xml/rs:data/z:row">
        <rfp>
          <title>
            <xsl:value-of select="@ows_RFP_x0020_Link" />
          </title>
          <applicationStart>
            <xsl:value-of select="@ows_Application_x0020_Period_x0020_S" />
          </applicationStart>
          <applicationEnd>
            <xsl:value-of select="@ows_Application_x0020_Period_x0020_E" />
          </applicationEnd>
          <programStart>
            <xsl:value-of select="@ows_Program_x0020_Start_x0020_Date" />
          </programStart>
          <publicURL>
            <xsl:value-of select="@ows_Public_x0020_Guidelines_x0020_Do" />
          </publicURL>
        </rfp>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </activeRFPs>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<activeRFPs xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20">
  <rfp>
    <title>http://www.google.com, Google Search Engine</title>
    <applicationStart>2012-06-22 00:00:00</applicationStart>
    <applicationEnd>2012-07-20 00:00:00</applicationEnd>
    <programStart>2012-10-01 00:00:00</programStart>
    <publicURL>http://www.yahoo.com</publicURL>
  </rfp>
</activeRFPs>
```

Comment: I did have that previously. When I run in Visual Studio, I get this output: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<activeRFPs xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" /> with the Output of The program '[2532] Microsoft.XslDebugger.Host.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Can you post some or all of your xml data so I can try it out for myself?  Thanks!

Comment: That xml doesn't quite look correct.  Can you verify that you added all of it?  Mine typically look like this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
  <s:Schema id="RowsetSchema">
     ... 
  </s:Schema>
  <rs:data ItemCount="15">
    <z:row />
  </rs:data>
</xml>

Comment: You're right--it was all there, but the code formatting was cutting it off. Updated again. Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer, see above.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? I copied your code and am getting XmlException
------------
's' is an undeclared prefix. Line 1, position 2.

Comment: Yea, i'm using VS.  I did add the line at the top of my XSLT which you didn't have.  Maybe try copying that into your project.